# Entity Framework nesting variables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, include, entity

I have the following setup in Entity:

```
public class t_HT
{
    public int UNID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<t_HTC> Comments { get; set; }

}
```

AND

```
public class t_HTC
{
    public int UNID { get; set; }

    public int HTID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HTID")]
    public t_HT HT { get; set; }

    public int CId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CId")]
    public t_C C { get; set; }
}
```

AND

```
public class t_C
{
    public int UNID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<t_HTC> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Where the relationships are as follows:

Many `t_HTC` to one `t_HT`

One `t_HT` to many `t_HTC`

AND

Many `t_HTC` to one `t_C`

One `t_C` to many `t_HTC`

This setup works fine and achieves what I need.

However, when querying using `C#` and `Linq/Entity` I can do the following:

```
var queryHt = context.ht.include(x => x.htc);
```

AND

```
var queryC = context.c.include(x => x.htc);
```

Either of these will return a single `t_ht` with a nested list of `t_htc` OR
a single `t_c` with a nested list of `t_htc`

However, what I want to achieve is:

a single `t_ht`, with a nested list of `t_htc`, and then for `t_htc` to include the corresponding entry in `t_c`

I know I can achieve this by performing a join that joins `queryC` into `queryHt` but this seems a bit of a long way to go about doing this.

Surely entity can achieve what I am trying to do?

Please note variable names have been adjusted for the purpose of this question, and are not like this in my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with this:

```
var queryHt = context.ht.Include("htc.C");
```

or with the [**strong typed** version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
var queryHt = context.ht.Include(x => x.htc.Select(y => y.C));
```

The strong typed version requires adding `using System.Data.Entity;`.